# How to make tabsize also affect lstinputlisting?

Tags: listings

I noticed that `tabsize` only affects `lstlisting` and `lstinline` macros.

Here is the output. The top figure is displayed using `lstinputlisting` and the bottom one
is displayed using `lstlisting`. The `tabsize` does not affect the top one. But it does for the bottom one.

[image]

How to make it works for all macros?

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames,rgb,table]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=20mm,vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset%
{%
    literate={ï}{}0
           {»}{}0
           {¿}{}0,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\color{White}\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{Orange}\sffamily\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\itshape,
    stringstyle=\color{Cyan}\rmfamily,
    showstringspaces=true,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    belowskip=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Black}%,
    %rangeprefix=\%,
    %rangesuffix=\%,
    %includerangemarker=false,
    %linerange=start-stop%
}


\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\def\MyOwn%
{%        
    \VerbatimEnvironment%
  \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}
\def\endMyOwn%
{%
    \end{VerbatimOut}% 
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}%     
}


\begin{document}
\begin{MyOwn}
using System;
class Foo
{
    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("using lstinputlisting");
    }
}
\end{MyOwn}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{lstlisting}
using System;
class Foo
{
    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("using lstlisting");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

---

Does the `\VerbatimEnvironment` cause this problem?

Comment: Look at the output file, does it contain tabs? If not, then tabsize doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use also:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{tabsize=2}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code? I can't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you do not have tabs but spaces instead.