# How can I have two spaces before the broken lines in inputlisting?

Tags: lists, pseudocode, fancytabs

I am using the solution from [How can I write line numbers inside boxed code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643008/127048). Its code with slightly changes:

```tex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.sol}
    function hello_world(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
            uint256 amount = 100
            return amount * 100
            return true;
        }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
    \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\newtcbinputlisting{\inputlisting}[2][]{%
    listing file={#2},
    top=0pt,
    left=16pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    right=8pt,
    colback=verylightgray,
    colframe=black,
    listing only,
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0.2pt,
    listing options={#1},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{Solidity}{
    keywords=[1]{% generic keywords including crypto operations
            anonymous, assembly, assert, balance, break, call, callcode, case,
            catch, class, constant, continue, constructor, contract, debugger,
            default, delegatecall, delete, do, else, emit, event, experimental,
            export, external, false, finally, for, function, gas, if, implements,
            import, in, indexed, instanceof, interface, internal, is, length,
            library, log0, log1, log2, log3, log4, memory, modifier, new, payable,
            pragma, private, protected, public, pure, push, require, return,
            returns, revert, selfdestruct, send, solidity, storage, struct,
            suicide, super, switch, then, this, throw, transfer, true, try,
            typeof, using, value, view, while, with, addmod, ecrecover, keccak256,
            mulmod, ripemd160, sha256, sha3
        },
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue}\bfseries,
    keywords=[2]{% types; money and time units
            address, bool, byte, bytes, bytes1, bytes2, bytes3, bytes4, bytes5,
            bytes6, bytes7, bytes8, bytes9, bytes10, bytes11, bytes12, bytes13,
            bytes14, bytes15, bytes16, bytes17, bytes18, bytes19, bytes20, bytes21,
            bytes22, bytes23, bytes24, bytes25, bytes26, bytes27, bytes28, bytes29,
            bytes30, bytes31, bytes32, enum, int, int8, int16, int24, int32, int40,
            int48, int56, int64, int72, int80, int88, int96, int104, int112, int120,
            int128, int136, int144, int152, int160, int168, int176, int184, int192,
            int200, int208, int216, int224, int232, int240, int248, int256, mapping,
            string, uint, uint8, uint16, uint24, uint32, uint40, uint48, uint56,
            uint64, uint72, uint80, uint88, uint96, uint104, uint112, uint120,
            uint128, uint136, uint144, uint152, uint160, uint168, uint176, uint184,
            uint192, uint200, uint208, uint216, uint224, uint232, uint240, uint248,
            uint256, var, void, ether, finney, szabo, wei, days, hours, minutes,
            seconds, weeks, years},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{teal}\bfseries,
    keywords=[3]{% environment variables
            block, blockhash, coinbase, difficulty, gaslimit, number, timestamp,
            msg, data, gas, sender, sig, value, now, tx, gasprice, origin
        },
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{violet}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstset{
    language=Solidity,
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=9pt,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    showtabs=false,
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\inputlisting{\jobname.sol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Seems like broken lines have four spaces.

Is it possible to have the linebreak tab size as two space? Please note that I have changed `tabsize=1` to smaller values but it did not have any effect.

As an example, see where there are two spaces before `uint d` and `bool {`:

```bash
function hello_world(uint a, uint b, uint c, 
  uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
  uint256 amount = 100
  return amount * 100
  return true;
}
```

Related:

- [How to make tabsize also affect lstinputlisting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8216/how-to-make-tabsize-also-affect-lstinputlisting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `breakindent`.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    breaklines,
    basewidth=0.6em,
    breakindent=1.2em,
    breakatwhitespace
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble]
    function hello_world(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return amount * 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,postbreak=\hbox{$\hookrightarrow$\space}]
    function hello_world(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return amount * 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I have set `basewidth` (which is the width of a character) explicitly so that `breakindent` can be set exactly to 2 characters wide. In case you wish to use, the second version prints a hook to distinguish a line break.

Output:

[image]

Comment: I can apply `[language=Solidity]` to appyly language colors right?

Comment: Yes, definitely! I have just given the bare settings required to achieve the two space indentation you asked for.

Comment: Thanks! it was exactly what I was looking for. In case for 4 space I just have to change `1.2em` to `2.4em` right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, can the width size to breakline increased?

Comment: It can be done. I had set it to `1.2em` since the question asks for two-space indent.

Comment: I had changed `1.2em` to a larger value like `1.5em` or more but it did not helped to increase the width per line  like I want `d,`  on the first line since there is more space at the end of the first line

Comment: @alper, I couldn't understand what you said. Perhaps an image of your desired output would help.